# The function $A$ is given by the formula $f(t)=4-t$ and integral from $A(x) = \int_0^x f(t) dt$

Tags: calculus

Sketch a graph of $y=A(x)$ for $0≤x≤4$.

Calculate the values of $A(0)$, $A(1)$, $A(2)$, and $A(3)$.

Determine the values of $A'(0)$, $A'(1)$, $A'(2)$, and $A'(3)$.

So I know the indefinite integral of $f(t)$ is $$4t - \frac{1}{2}t^{2} + c$$
But I'm not really sure what the next step is.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does `A^' (0)` etc. mean?

Comment: Did you mean $A(x) = \int_0^x f(t) dt$?  Also, please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: A'(0) is what I meant to write  and yes I mean that @N.F.Taussig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indefinite integral is correct but the integral you are using is definite. The constants are not needed as they cancel out.

Note that the definite integral has the formula $\int_{a}^{b}f(x){dx}=(F(b)+c)-(F(a)+c)=F(b)-F(a)$, where $F(x)$ is the indefinite integral.

So $\int_{0}^{x}{(4-t)}{dt}=|_{0}^{x}4t-\frac{1}{2}t^2=\left(4(x)-\frac{1}{2}(x)^2+c\right)-(4(0)-\frac{1}{2}(0)+c)=-\frac{1}{2}x^2+4x$

Now just substitute the values $x=0,1,2,3$

Finally for $A'(x)$ just take the derivative of the resulting function.

$\frac{d}{dx}\left(-\frac{1}{2}x^2+4x\right)=-x+4$

Then substitute $x=0,1,2,3$ once again.

Comment: No need to compute the derivative since that’s what you started out with.

Comment: @amd True, I was too lazy to explain that so I computed the derivative.

Comment: That is kind of the point of the exercise, though.

Answer (score 1):

By definition,
$$A(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f(t)~dt$$
where $f(t) = 4 - t$.  Evaluating the integral yields
\begin{align*}
A(x) & = \int_{0}^{x} (4 - t)~dt\\
     & = \left(4t - \frac{1}{2}t^2\right) \bigg|_{0}^{x}\\
     & = 4x - \frac{1}{2}x^2 - (0 - 0)\\
     & = 4x - \frac{1}{2}x^2
\end{align*}
Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 1):

Well, then $$A(x) = \left[4t - \frac{1}{2}t^2\right]_0^x$$
$$A(x) = 4x - \frac{1}{2}x^2$$
$$A(x) = \frac{1}{2}\left(8x - x^2\right)$$
$$A(x) = \frac{1}{2}x\left(8 - x\right)$$
The graph of $A(x)$ will be a downward parabola cutting the x-axis at $0$ and $8$.
$$A'(x) = \frac{1}{2}\left(8 - 2x\right) = 4 - x$$